# saving NSString from Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsstring, textinput

I know this should be easy but I cannot get a string from a text input to save to core data.  My string saves as null.  My code is

```
NSString *courseName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", _courseNameValue.text];
```

Then saving to core data with

```
[newRound setValue:courseName forKey:@"roundCourseName"];
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you check if `_courseNameValue` is nil? Or if `newRound` is nil? did you *save* the managed object context?

Comment: newRound is not nil because I have other values from text input that are correctly saving.  I don't believe _courseNameValue is nil but I will check.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Solved my problem.  I had a weird situation where the input field was really formatted as a label.  Changed to text input, hooked up outlet, and it's fixed now.  Explains why I couldn't fix the problem with code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Need more code, but try this code :

```
@synthesize courseNameValue;
NSString *f = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", courseNameValue.text];
[newRound setValue:courseName forKey:@"roundCourseName"];
```

ps check the courseNameValue

Comment: I have tried something similar to that, but it also won't work because you are creating a pointer that is not used in saving the string to core data.

Comment: @tnb121  Oh sorry,  NSString * courseName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", courseNameValue.text];